# connect qemu/kvm(managed by virsh) VM to an existing tap device

Tags: qemu, libvirt, virsh, tap

I'm using `virsh` to manage my `qemu`/`kvm` VMs. Problematic VM has the following interface configuration:

```
<interface type='bridge'>
  <mac address='52:54:00:92:f7:f8'/>
  <source bridge='br-PC-LAN1'/>
  <target dev='tap0'/>
  <model type='rtl8139'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
```

`tap0` is already created by my OS network configuration files, i.e I want my VM to use an existing tap device and not create a new one. Now when I start the VM, then I receive the `error: Unable to add bridge br-PC-LAN1 port tap0: Device or resource busy` error message.

Is it possible to connect a VM to an existing tap device rather than creating an new one?